# binary file containing C data structure access with python

Tags: python, c

I have a binary file where the data is filled with a "C" data structure. I want to access this using Python. I have seen a couple of posts regarding `struct` in python.  However, I could not get a clear idea on how to use this with my requirement.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

`This is what i Wanted`

```
import struct


def write():
    values = (3 , 'name' , 6.6)
    s = struct.Struct('i4sf')   
    packed_data = s.pack(*values)

    fname = '123.sample'
    f = open(fname , 'wb')
    f.write(packed_data)
    f.close()


def read():
    fname = '123.sample'
    f = open(fname , 'rb')
    data = f.read()

    data_val = struct.unpack('i4sf' , data)

    print data_val
```

Comment: The `struct` module is used all the time for this kind of thing.  To get a helpful answer, you'll have to show the C code defining the C `struct`.

Comment: @TimPeters is this THE Tim Peters?

Comment: @AnuragUniyal, that depends on which Tim Peters you have in mind - LOL.  But, ya, probably ;-)

Comment: @TimPeters I mean 'import this'

Comment: I have edited the question with an answer. This is what i wanted

Answer (score 3):

This is a very generic question, struct module provides ways to pack and unpack binary data, if you know the format correctly you can represent it using struct format and unpack it. e.g. to pack and unpack a unsigned short and a char use this:

```
>>> import struct
>>> data = struct.pack('Hc',255, 'a')
>>> struct.unpack('Hc', data)
(255, 'a')
```

So go through [struct module docs](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/struct.html), and try to unpack your data and if you are stuck then you can ask specific questions.

Comment: Thanks @anurag I have added a sample of what i needed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @rakesh looks like you are using it correctly, so what is the problem?

Comment: .I do not have any problem now, i finally found out. i just posted my answer.